# Application-wide and page-specific output cache in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching

Page-specific output cache is controlled using `outputCacheSettings` section in `web.config`, where it's possible to specify parameters like duration. Use of this setting requires `@OutputCache` directive in the pages to be cached.

Application-wide output cache is controlled using `outputCache` section. This section has only few parameters and doesn't include things like duration.

But can application-wide output cache be set up without editing pages if I want to apply the same caching parameters to the whole site? And if so how can I specify parameters like duration that belong to `outputCacheSettings`?